# In Commerce 2, how can we allow users with a role to bypass payment during checkout (bill me later)

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

We have a Commerce 2 site that we need to be able to assign users a role ('Bill Me Later') that will allow the user to select the payment option 'Bill Me Later' during checkout.

I have not found a module that provides this functionality. I started to dive into creating a custom payment processor but I'm not sure if this is the correct route to go. If the user were to select 'Bill Me Later' then no further information would be needed. The order would go through (completed) but now marked paid.

Could someone offer some insight into the best way to achieve this? We're open to building a custom payment gateway module if that is required but could use a little guidance as to get started since this technically is not a payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the "Commerce Payment Example" module that comes with commerce2. From there on, go to commerce->settings->payment->payment gateways and add a new payment gateway. Choose the "Manual" plugin and set the proper roles on the bottom and you should be done.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The manual example method kind of works but it still requires that the user enter their billing name and address. Is there a way to disable this since that information would already be on record?